# How to insert the result of ST_Intersection into another column when the result has multiple geometry types

Tags: postgis, intersection, st-geometry

In PostGIS I have three tables `table1`, `table2` and `table3` of same type:

```
CREATE TABLE tableX
(
    myid integer NOT NULL,
    wkb_geometry geometry(LineString,4326)
)
```

`table1` and `table2` are populated. I want to intersect the linestrings of `table1` and `table2` and insert the result into `table3` like this:

```
insert into table3 (
    select
        table1.myid,
        ST_Intersection(table1.wkb_geometry, table2.wkb_geometry)
    from table1, table2
)
```

The result of `ST_Intersection()` is sometimes of type **LineString** and sometimes of type **MultiLineString**. Therefore I am getting an error:

```
ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiLineString) does not match column type (LineString)
```

And if I change the geometry type of `table3` to MultiLineString I am getting the opposite error:

```
ERROR:  Geometry type (LineString) does not match column type (MultiLineString)
```

What is an elegant way to store the results of this intersection, but **preserving** the original information if the intersection was LineString or MultiLineString?

Is there no 'flexible' geometry type for columns which could hold results of both types?

( If possible I do not want to normalize the results with `ST_Multi`, because later I would need to decompose with `ST_Dump` )

Comment: I suppose that this is documented somewhere but create the table as `wkb_geometry geometry(Geometry,4326)`.

Comment: Hi  @user30184, yes `wkb_geometry geometry(Geometry,4326)` column type works. Thanks a lot. I could not find it in the documentation.

Comment: One place is https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_usage.html#geometry_columns, read about "type". `For heterogeneous (mixed-type) collections, you can use "GEOMETRY" as the type.`